# best path between 2 nodes based on conditions

Tags: neo4j

I m having a network of nodes N with value V between each 2 nodes.
is there please a way to fromulate a calculation in Cypher where I am looking to find out the best path between 2 nodes based on the condition below:

- The path choice between a node and direct candidates C1,C2.. will be the based on the highest value of V1,V2..
- This rule should apply from the start node S till the end node E.
- I enclosed here an example with with few nodes just as an illustrations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDOVV.png)
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing a Neo4j plugin called Graph Data Science. It has existing path-finding algorithms that can help you create the Cypher query for your graph.

[Neo4j Graph Data Science - Path Finding Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/pathfinding/)